# tvOS - Firebase/Core supported? Any other way to get remote Push Notification in tvOS Application?

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, tvos11

When I try to use the Firebase framework with tvOS (via cocoapods) I get the following error:

```
> [!] The platform of the target `*******` (tvOS 9.0) is not compatible
> with `Firebase/Core (4.8.0)`, which does not support `tvos`.
```

I tried to set platform as 'tvos' to 'ios' and vice-versa in Podfile, but in both case, same warning occurred. By searching in the web, I figured it out that the Firebase/Core and Firebase/Messaging modules are not stable yet. Did anybody worked on such module where they worked on getting Remote Push Notifications in tvOS Application from Firebase. If yes, then it will be of great help if you can **provide any example or tutorial for your solution**. Also, if there are other ways around to get Remote Push Notifications in tvOS Applications, please do share. **Do take note that the whole project is participated by different platforms.**

Comment: FirebaseMessaging has not yet been ported to tvOS.  It is dependent upon https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/186. More details about the current status of Firebase and tvOS at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk#macos-and-tvos

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that macOS, tvOS, watchOS and Catalyst are not officially supported by Firebase